# Converting a Linux host to Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualization, fedora

On my PC I am currently running Fedora 12. I would like to convert that and the filesystem to a Virtual Machine, so that I can install Windows 7 as the main operating system and have this Fedora 12 as a VM in VMWare or VirtualBox or some such Desktop Virtualization system.

Is this possible and how if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible with VMWare Workstation 7 on a Linux host, but it is possible (using File->Import) on a Windows host. The application that does the work is called VMWare Converter and it is available as a separate download. Options include:

- Import a remote machine
- Import a dual boot system source

Chapter 6 in the [Workstation User's Manual](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/ws7_manual.pdf) explains the options.

Workstation 7 is licensed for either Windows or Linux, so you should be able to move your license to Windows without additional cost, as long as you have Workstation 7.

Answer (score 0):

easiest thing to do is to simply set up the VM, start it up with a liveCD attached, and use dd over netcat from the physical source host into the VM

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the live CD version [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/) to save your Linux image off and then restore as a VM.